# defining function in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This is my **rooms.js.coffee**.

```
allowDrop = (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()
drag = (ev) ->
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("image", ev.target.id)
drop = (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()
    data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("image")
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
```

When I run server and debug using firefox (pressing F12), there are two errors.

```
ReferenceError: drag is not defined 
ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined
```

The generated Javascript is as follows.

```
(function() {
  var allowDrop, drag, drop;

  allowDrop = function(ev) {
    return ev.preventDefault();
  };

  drag = function(ev) {
    return ev.dataTransfer.setData("image", ev.target.id);
  };

  drop = function(ev) {
    var data;
    ev.preventDefault();
    data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("image");
    return ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  };

}).call(this);
```

I think this is elementary problem, but I can't solve this. Could you tell me how to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the functions are contextualized.

If you want to declare global functions, use:

```
window.allowDrop = (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()
```